# Is there a way to upgrade Ubuntu 16.04 to 16.10 in parts?

Tags: upgrade, updates, 16.10

I use 3G/4G but connection is not good these days. I tried to update to get rid of few problems got introduced after recent updates. But my slow connection is not allowing me to upgrade to 16.10.

**Is there a way to update in part and have working laptop after every part  update?**
I am using the popup alert coming for asking to upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think what you're asking is possible. However, rather than trying to upgrade online, you might be better off downloading the [.iso for 16.10](http://cdimages.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/releases/16.10/release/), burning it to disc or writing to USB, and then upgrading from local media instead. If you're pulling the torrent or using a download manager that is capable of resuming dropped connections, it might take a while, but the update process itself will not be affected by your Internet connection. Just be sure to verify the checksum when your download is complete.

Comment: May be that is the only solution to me. For me at 3rd/4rd step, when it starts pulling packages then it stuck. Packages 451 out of say 1600. Long way to go. Not moving forward after this.